# Insert CSV file into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I want to insert a csv file in my database using php. I tried the following code but it gives the following error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function exec() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\ICT_project\class.import.php on line 25

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';

class Import {
private $pdo;

public function __construct() {
    $obj_connect = new DBconnect();
    $this->pdo = $obj_connect->db_con;

}

public function import_csv() {

    $extension= end(explode(".", basename($_FILES['file']['name'])));
    if (isset($_FILES['file']) && $_FILES['file']['size'] < 10485760 && $extension=='csv') {
        $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; 
        $handle = fopen($file, "r"); 
        try {           
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                //$num = count($data);

            $importSQL = "INSERT INTO tbl_applicants(application_no, applicant_name,applicant_email, applicant_mobile, applicant_address) VALUES('$data[0]','$data[1]')";

            $this->pdo->exec($importSQL);  
            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

    }
}
```

My `tbl_applicants` have five fields named: `application_no`, `applicant_name`, `applicant_email`, `applicant_mobile`, `applicant_address`.
In csv file i have tow row of data with above five fields. I do not understand what will be the insert query?

Hi, here is the updated code which works fine. **Now I want to skip the first row of my .csv file** which generally contains header(id,name, email, address). How can i do this?

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';

class Import {
    private $pdo;

    public function __construct() {     
        $obj_connection = new Db_connection();
        $this->pdo = $obj_connection->connection();     
    }

    public function import_csv() {

        $extension= end(explode(".", basename($_FILES['file']['name'])));
        if (isset($_FILES['file']) && $_FILES['file']['size'] < 10485760 && $extension=='csv') {
            $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; 
            $handle = fopen($file, "r"); 
            try {           
                while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {                   
                $importSQL = "INSERT INTO tbl_applicants ( application_no, applicant_name, applicant_email, applicant_mobile, applicant_address ) VALUES('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]')";
                $this->pdo->query($importSQL);  
                }
            }
            catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please add all values of fields that you have addded in insert query.
(application_no, applicant_name,applicant_email, applicant_mobile, applicant_address) 5 fields for insert query and on values only 2 VALUES('$data[0]','$data[1]'). Please add all files in values or put it as blank

Comment: the sql query has five fields referenced yet you only supply two pieces of data as input

Answer (score 0):

Please replace this insert query with above query.

```
$importSQL = "INSERT INTO tbl_applicants
            (application_no, applicant_name,applicant_email, applicant_mobile, applicant_address) 
             VALUES('$data[0]','$data[1]','','','')";
```

Comment: I think you meant `$importSQL = "INSERT INTO tbl_applicants(application_no, applicant_name,applicant_email, applicant_mobile, applicant_address) VALUES('{$data[0]}','{$data[1]}','','','')";` ;)
`

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function exec() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\ICT_project\class.import.php on line 25

Comment: @NishanSingha Please first check query is run property or not so you need to echo insert query and run it in phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0):

having not seen the data it is just a guess beased on what you have used above but perhaps you just need to add the remaining fields from the csv?

```
$importSQL = "INSERT INTO `tbl_applicants`
   ( application_no, applicant_name, applicant_email, applicant_mobile, applicant_address ) 
   VALUES
   ('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]')"
```

Comment: This give me 
Notice: Undefined offset: 2
Notice: Undefined offset: 3
Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in C:\xampp\htdocs\ICT_project\class.import.php on line 23